# How to fix an undefined json in angular?

Tags: json, angular

I have a form with a uploader input to get an image "angular-file-uploader" npm library. but in the function that receive the data, it receive the data undefined, I can't do a JSON.parse() with the data.

I don't know if the problem is in the backend (nodejs) but with postman the backend works.

```
 <angular-file-uploader #fileUpload1
    [config]="afuConfig"
    [resetUpload]=resetVar
    (ApiResponse)="avatarUpload($event)">
</angular-file-uploader>

    this.afuConfig = {
        multiple: false,
        formatsAllowed: '.jpg, .jpeg, .png, .gif',
        maxSize: '50',
        uploadAPI:{
          url: this.url+'upload-avatar',
          headers:{
          // 'Content-Type' : 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8',
            'Authorization': this.token
          }
        },
        theme: 'attachPin',
        hideProgressBar: false,
        hideResetBtn: true,
        hideSelectBtn: false,
        attachPinText:'Sube la imagen'
    };

  }

avatarUpload(book)
{
  console.log(book); //here the error is TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

  let data = JSON.parse(book.response);// here core.js:6228 ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0
  this.book.image = data.book.image;
  console.log(data);

}
```

backend nodejs function uploadAvatar()

```
uploadAvatar: function(req, res){
        // Configurar el modulo multiparty (md) routes/user.js

        // Recoger el fichero de la petición
         var file_name = 'imagen no subida...';


        if(!req.files){
            return res.status(404).send({
                    status: 'error',
                    message: file_name
            });
        }

        // Conseguir el nombre y la extension del archivo
        var file_path = req.params.file0.path;
    //  var file_split = file_path.split('\\');

        // ** Adventencia ** En linux o mac
        var file_split = file_path.split('/');

        // Nombre del archivo
        var file_name = file_split[2];

        // Extensión del archivo
        var ext_split = file_name.split('\.');
        var file_ext = ext_split[1];

        // Comprobar extension (solo imagenes), si no es valida borrar fichero subido
        if(file_ext != 'png' && file_ext != 'jpg' && file_ext != 'jpeg' && file_ext != 'gif'){
            fs.unlink(file_path, (err) => {

                return res.status(200).send({
                    status: 'error',
                    message: 'La extensión del archivo no es valida.'
                });

            });

        }else{
            // Sacar el id del libro
      var params = req.body;
            var bookId = req.params.bookId;

            // Buscar y actualizar documento bd
            Book.findOneAndUpdate({_id: bookId}, {image: file_name}, {new:true}, (err, bookUpdated) => {

                if(err || !bookUpdated){
                    // Devolver respuesta
                    return res.status(500).send({
                            status: 'error',
                            message: 'Error al guardar la imagen'
                        });
                }

                // Devolver respuesta
                return res.status(200).send({
                        status: 'success',
                        image: book.image,
                        user: bookUpdated
                    });

            });
 }
    },
```

Edited

```
console.log(book);
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at http.js:168
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HttpHeaders.lazyInit (http.js:156)
    at HttpHeaders.init (http.js:277)
    at HttpHeaders.forEach (http.js:379)
    at Observable._subscribe (http.js:2398)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
    at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:28)
    at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:9)

avatarUpload(book)
{
  console.log(book); //here the error is TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

  let data = JSON.parse(book.response);// here core.js:6228 ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0
  this.book.image = data.book.image;
  console.log(book);

}
at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (mergeMap.js:59)
```

Comment: did you check what is in the book object?

Comment: how to check it? with a console.log? the form has other inputs text etc..

Answer (score 0):

book.response is not a json object. That is why you getting the following error while  trying to parse it.

```
let data = JSON.parse(book.response);
// here core.js:6228 ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position.
```

Can you please update question with book data?

Comment: with book data? I don't underestand it

Comment: console.log(book); can you share what u get in this book object?